# converting indexes to iterators

Tags: c++, indexing, iterator, openframeworks

I would like to recreate the following code with iterators just for learning purposes. The following code checks the boundary of a box in openFrameworks, basically it checks that whenever my mouse position is on one of the 4 rectangles, it will turn a boolean to true and the others to false. I have been very fond of iterators lately but for some reason I couldn't make this work with iterators, since the index returns the position of the object in the vector, the iterator returns a pointer to the object in that position specifically. Here is the code:

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < answersBox.size(); i++){
    for ( int j = 0; j < isHovered.size(); j++){
        if( x > answersBox[i].x && x < (answersBox[i].x + answersBox[i].width) && y > answersBox[i].y && y < (answersBox[i].y + answersBox[i].height)){
         if( i == j){
                isHovered[j] = true;
                cout << "This boolean number: " << j << " has become: " << isHovered[j] << endl;
            }else if( i != j){
                isHovered[j] = false;
            }
            }{
                cout << " These booleans number: " << j << " have become: " << isHovered[j] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: in your code, when `i==j` is false, `i!=j` is true, you don't have to check it, you can simply write `if(i==j){/*something*/} else{/*something*/}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not just blindly turn *all* index-based loops into iterator-based ones. As you have discovered, index-based loops can sometimes be better (as in: easier to read, write, understand and maintain).

In particular, the following piece of code:

```
if( i == j)
```

is a good indicator that an index-based loop is better *for this particular problem*.

If you *really really* want to try it with iterators, have a look at [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). Using that function, you can replace the index comparison with:

```
if (std::distance(answersBox.begin(), iter1) == std::distance(isHovered.begin(), iter2)
```

---

By the way, the `else if( i != j)` doesn't make sense, as the condition will always be true. You can replace it with a simple `else`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't make this code working on iterators, because you can't compare two iterators, pointing to different containers.

If you want to compare iterators as indexes, you can write

```
if(i-answersBox.begin()==j-isHovered.begin() )
```

Comment: You seem to be thinking of [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). Yours will only work on `RandomAccessIterators`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<AnswerBox, bool> > answers_type;
answers_type answersBox;

for (answers_type::iterator i = answersBox.begin(); i != answersBox.end(); ++i)
{
  i->second = i->first->contains(x, y);
}
```

where the vector stores both, AnswerBox and whether or not it is hovered.

Here I used the more object oriented approach of defining

```
bool AnswerBox::contains(float x, float y) const
{
  return x > m_x && y > m_y && x < m_x + m_width && y < m_y + m_height;
}
```

where m_* are the member variables of AnswerBox (added the prefix).

PS Even better is to use a custom class for the std::pair. Makes things a lot more readable often. Ie, have `std::vector<AnswerBoxHovered>` where the element contains an `AnswerBox` and a `bool m_is_hovered`. And you get code like:

```
i->set_is_hovered(x, y);
```

where

```
void AnswerBoXHovered::set_is_hovered(float x, float y)
{
  m_is_hovered = m_answer_box.contains(x, y);
}
```

etc.

Comment: This looks quite interesting will definitely give it a try

Comment: How do you push_back to a vector like that?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out: make_pair() and then I push that element. Yes I agree that the best way to do it is to have a custom class that contains the rectangle and the boolean. thanks for replying!